# How to check if the users selection is the correct answer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a quiz app for practice in Javascript and have created all the questions.. I have made it go to the next question when the "Next Question button" is clicked, and have the correct answer console logging, but can't find out how to implement it to see if it matches the users input. If I can track it, I will add it to a "currentScore counter"

CODE:

```js
let question = document.querySelector('.question')
let answerbox = document.querySelector('.answer-container')
let quizbox = document.querySelector('.quiz-container')
let answer1 = document.getElementById('a1')
let answer2 = document.getElementById('a2')
let answer3 = document.getElementById('a3')
let answer4 = document.getElementById('a4')
let answers = document.getElementsByClassName('answer')
let submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn')
let currentquestion = 0
let currentscore = 0

const questionsData = [{
    question: "How old am I?",
    answers: {
      a: "18",
      b: "21",
      c: "25",
      d: "35",
    },
    correctAnswer: "b"
  },
  {
    question: "What is my favorite color?",
    answers: {
      a: "Purple",
      b: "Green",
      c: "Black",
      d: "Red",
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "What is my middle name?",
    answers: {
      a: "Albert",
      b: "David",
      c: "Graham",
      d: "John",
    },
    correctAnswer: "d"
  },
]

const loadquestion = () => {
  console.log('working!!!')
  //GETTING THE CORRECT ANSWER //
  let correctAnswer = (questionsData[currentquestion].correctAnswer)
  console.log(correctAnswer)
  //RESET CLICK WHEN CLICKED OUTSIDE
  const clickreset = (e) => {
    if (e.target !== quizbox) {
      // console.log(answer1.checked)
      answer1.checked = false
      answer2.checked = false
      answer3.checked = false
      answer4.checked = false
    } else {
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('click', clickreset)
  // console.log(questionsData[currentquestion].answers)
  //INPUTTING THE QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS FROM THE QUIZDATE
  question.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].question
  answer1.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.a
  answer2.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.b
  answer3.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.c
  answer4.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.d
  for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    let answerels = answers[i];
    //RESETTING THE SELECTED ANSWER WHEN THE USER MOVES ON TO THE NEXT QUESTION
    answerels.checked = false
  }

  currentquestion++
}

loadquestion()

const endofquiz = () => {
  //GIVING RESULTS AT THE END
  question.innerText = 'You answered ___ out of ___'
  answer1.style.opacity = '0'
  answer2.style.opacity = '0'
  answer3.style.opacity = '0'
  answer4.style.opacity = '0'
  submitBtn.innerText = 'Restart Quiz'
  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    location.reload()
  })
}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  //KEEP TRACK OF QUESTIONS UNTIL QUIZ IS FINISHED
  if (currentquestion < questionsData.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      let answerels = answers[i];
      //CHECK TO SEE IF USER HAS SELECTED AN ANSWER
      if (answerels.checked == true) {
        //CHECK TO SEE IF USER HAS SELECTED AN ANSWER
        //MOVE ON TO NEXT QUESTION
        loadquestion()
        // console.log('checked!')
      } else {
        //STOP USER FROM GOING TO NEXT QUESTION WITHOUT SELECTING AN ANSWER
        // console.log('not checked! :(')
      }
    }
  } else {
    // SHOW RESULTS 
    endofquiz()
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.quiz-container {
  margin-top: 3em;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

.question-container {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 80vh;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 10%;
        left: 50%; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -10%); */
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

.question {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.answer-container {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -5em;
  flex-direction: column;
}

label {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223);
}

label:hover {
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.45s ease;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.45s ease;
}

.submit-btn {
  margin-top: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223);
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  width: 10%;
}

.submit-btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  transition: 0.45s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz-container">
      <div class="question-container">
        <h1 class="question">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, inventore.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="answer-container">
        <input class="answer" id='an1' type="radio" name="a"></input> <label id="a1" for="an1">lorem</label>
        <input class="answer" id='an2' type="radio" name="a"></input> <label id="a2" for="an2">lorem</label>
        <input class="answer" id='an3' type="radio" name="a"></input> <label id="a3" for="an3">lorem</label>
        <input class="answer" id='an4' type="radio" name="a"></input> <label id="a4" for="an4">lorem</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="submit-btn" id="submit-btn">Next Question</button>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Whats ur problem? What have u tried?

Comment: A small question: if you include the correct answer client side, then people can just look up the right answer in their dev tools, bypassing whatever the purpose of your questionaire is. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Yes, that's acceptable for now. I am trying to find a way to see what answer the user has selected when they move on to the next question, so I can see if it matches the correct answer, I am just doing this for learning purposes

Answer (score 0):

Give each answer button a value that corresponds to the answer keys in the `questionsData` array. Then you can check if the selected button matches `correctAnswer`.

Also make `correctAnswer` a global variable so you can use it in the submit button listener.

I needed to make some changes to the logic of when it calls `loadquestion()` or `endofquiz()`, so that it checks the result of the last question and still calls `endofquiz()` at the end.

```js
let question = document.querySelector('.question')
let answerbox = document.querySelector('.answer-container')
let quizbox = document.querySelector('.quiz-container')
let answer1 = document.getElementById('a1')
let answer2 = document.getElementById('a2')
let answer3 = document.getElementById('a3')
let answer4 = document.getElementById('a4')
let answers = document.getElementsByClassName('answer')
let submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn')
let currentquestion = 0
let currentscore = 0
let correctAnswer = ''

const questionsData = [{
    question: "How old am I?",
    answers: {
      a: "18",
      b: "21",
      c: "25",
      d: "35",
    },
    correctAnswer: "b"
  },
  {
    question: "What is my favorite color?",
    answers: {
      a: "Purple",
      b: "Green",
      c: "Black",
      d: "Red",
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "What is my middle name?",
    answers: {
      a: "Albert",
      b: "David",
      c: "Graham",
      d: "John",
    },
    correctAnswer: "d"
  },
]

const loadquestion = () => {
  //console.log('working!!!')
  //GETTING THE CORRECT ANSWER //
  correctAnswer = (questionsData[currentquestion].correctAnswer)
  //console.log(correctAnswer)
  //RESET CLICK WHEN CLICKED OUTSIDE
  const clickreset = (e) => {
    if (e.target !== quizbox) {
      // console.log(answer1.checked)
      answer1.checked = false
      answer2.checked = false
      answer3.checked = false
      answer4.checked = false
    } else {}
  }
  window.addEventListener('click', clickreset)
  // console.log(questionsData[currentquestion].answers)
  //INPUTTING THE QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS FROM THE QUIZDATE
  question.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].question
  answer1.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.a
  answer2.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.b
  answer3.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.c
  answer4.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.d
  for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    let answerels = answers[i];
    //RESETTING THE SELECTED ANSWER WHEN THE USER MOVES ON TO THE NEXT QUESTION
    answerels.checked = false
  }
  currentquestion++

}

loadquestion()

const endofquiz = () => {
  //GIVING RESULTS AT THE END
  question.innerText = `You answered ${currentscore} out of ${questionsData.length}`
  answer1.style.opacity = '0'
  answer2.style.opacity = '0'
  answer3.style.opacity = '0'
  answer4.style.opacity = '0'
  submitBtn.innerText = 'Restart Quiz'
  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    location.reload()
  })
}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  //KEEP TRACK OF QUESTIONS UNTIL QUIZ IS FINISHED
  if (currentquestion <= questionsData.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      let answerels = answers[i];
      //CHECK TO SEE IF USER HAS SELECTED AN ANSWER
      if (answerels.checked == true) {
        //CHECK TO SEE IF USER HAS SELECTED AN ANSWER
        //MOVE ON TO NEXT QUESTION
        if (answerels.value == correctAnswer) {
          console.log("That's correct!");
          currentscore++;
        } else {
          console.log(`Sorry, the correct answer is ${questionsData[currentquestion-1].answers[correctAnswer]}.`);
        }
        if (currentquestion < questionsData.length) {
          loadquestion();
        } else {
          endofquiz();
        }
      } else {
        //STOP USER FROM GOING TO NEXT QUESTION WITHOUT SELECTING AN ANSWER
        // console.log('not checked! :(')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.quiz-container {
  margin-top: 3em;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

.question-container {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 80vh;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 10%;
        left: 50%; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -10%); */
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

.question {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.answer-container {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -5em;
  flex-direction: column;
}

label {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223);
}

label:hover {
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.45s ease;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.45s ease;
}

.submit-btn {
  margin-top: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223);
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  width: 10%;
}

.submit-btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  transition: 0.45s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz-container">
      <div class="question-container">
        <h1 class="question">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, inventore.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="answer-container">
        <input class="answer" id='an1' type="radio" name="a" value="1"></input> <label id="a1" for="an1">lorem</label>
        <input class="answer" id='an2' type="radio" name="a" value="b"></input> <label id="a2" for="an2">lorem</label>
        <input class="answer" id='an3' type="radio" name="a" value="c"></input> <label id="a3" for="an3">lorem</label>
        <input class="answer" id='an4' type="radio" name="a" value="d"></input> <label id="a4" for="an4">lorem</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="submit-btn" id="submit-btn">Next Question</button>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```